# Codeigniter Character Encoding Issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, character-encoding

I have a few simple pages which have no database data, and are just statically loaded from the controller. I have set everything possible to `UTF-8` encoding. I have checked headers, which result to `UTF-8`. However, it still parses wrong showing these characters: ���.

**Controller**:

```
function index(){

    $this->load->view('french/header_view');
    $this->load->view('french/homepage_view');
    $this->load->view('french/footer_view');

}
```

**Config File**:

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

**Header View**:

```
<? header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
....
```

**Characters Used in Body View**:

> géniales - à -  époustouflant

**Characters generated**:

> � se g�niales !

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the data is not encoded in UTF-8. Have you checked the encoding settings of your editor?

Answer (score 1):

Old but still relevant:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/08/UTF-8-support-for-CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Dreamweaver CS4, but I fixed it with Notepad++ (FREE!).

1.- Use Notepad++ -> Format -> Convert to UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM.

2.- Save.

3.- REVIEW again the file **and correct** the characters showing wrong.

4.- Save again.

5.- You're done.

(Also make sure in the config file in CI you have UTF8).

*For me at least it worked that way (Spanish).*